# How to split the csv data to two different kafka topics based on filter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Topic **Customer** in which I streamed a
csv file. Now is it possible to transform the data in kafka based on the [image: CSV]
**Counts**.  like if the count is **less** than 20 send it to **topic A** and if the counts is **greater** than 20 send it to **topic B**
**I am new to kafka and i was trying like this but its not working**

```
 builder.stream("Customer")
            .groupByKey()
            .count()
            .toStream()
            .filter((k,v)-> String(v) > 20)
            .to("test_A");
```

This code is wrong i am pretty sure about it , but please can anyone helpme out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is to create a producer and read a row at a time from your input csv file and as per count condition send it to particular topic.

```
psuedo code:
while no row left in csv:
    row = readrow()
    if row.counts<20
       producer.send(topicA,row)
    else
       producer.send(topicB,row)
```

you can follow https://towardsdatascience.com/kafka-python-explained-in-10-lines-of-code-800e3e07dad1 for ease understanding of kafka with python

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing right now is to send only a part of the records to one topic based on a condition a discard the others. If you want to send part of then to one topic and the others to other topic you should use the branch operator.

Something like this:

```
KStream<K, Long>[] branches = builder.stream("Customer")
        .groupByKey()
        .count()
        .toStream()
        .branch((k, v) -> v > 20),
                (k, v) -> v <= 20);
branches[0].to("topicB");
branches[1].to("topicA");
```

Another thing you should note is the comparation must be between numbers, not strings because when you use greater comparator with strings you are comparing the length and lexicographical order of the strings

Answer (score 0):

```
   StreamsBuilder builder=new StreamsBuilder();


    KStream<String, String> inputTopic = builder.stream("Trans_Topic");

            inputTopic
                   .filter((k,v)->{
                       return Long.parseLong(v.split(",")[6]) < 20L; //6 is the column id.
                   }).to("trans_topic_result_1");
    inputTopic
            .filter((k,v)->{
                return Long.parseLong(v.split(",")[6]) > 20L;
            }).to("trans_topic_result_2");
```